# Finding row of value X in column A, and inserting value Y in the same row, in column B

Tags: sql, excel

I have two columns: Timestamp and Data. From Excel I will have a Timestamp datapoint (e.g., 2017-11-25 10:25:00) and a value related to it. Meanwhile in the database I will have the Timestamp column populated with different timestamps and I want to find the one that comes from Excel in this column, and insert the value in that same row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn about UPDATE statement and WHERE clause for SQL but here is an example, (this is assuming you are using SQL Server, but overall the syntax should be quite similar if not using SQL Server):

```
UPDATE [yourTable]
SET [DATA] = [Excel value]
WHERE [TimeStamp] = [ExcelTimeStamp]
```

Comment: I appreciate it Ryan, will have a look and come back if I'm not able to make it work!